# Problema con el instalador Squirrel de Electron Forge: la aplicación se abre con un GIF de carga, se cierra y se vuelve a abrir

Tags: electron, electron-forge, squirrel-windows

He creado una aplicación Electron y he utilizado el comando `npm run make`, que ejecuta `electron-forge make`. Todo funciona bien, pero al ejecutar el instalador generado "Setup.exe" con `@electron-forge/maker-squirrel`, la aplicación se abre simultáneamente con un GIF de carga. Después de que el GIF termina de cargar, tanto el GIF como la aplicación se cierran y luego se vuelven a abrir. No quiero que la aplicación se abra antes de que se cierre el GIF, o al menos que no sea visible. ¿Alguna sugerencia sobre cómo manejar este comportamiento?

#### Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.2.0",
    "electron": "28.0.0",
    "electron-reloader": "^1.2.3"
  }
```

#### Scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\""
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadiendo el siguiente código a tu main.js se soluciona:

```
if(require("electron-squirrel-startup")) {
  app.quit();
}
```